# How to access whitelist Azure SQL db from an WPF application running on several laptops

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, azure

I have developed an WPF application with a SQLite db.
I want to migrate the SQLite db to Azure SQL db, but in order to keep up the security i need to white list IPs in the firewall in Azure.

The app is going to be installed on several laptops, which should be able to run the app from different unknown wifi connections.

How will I be able to grand the app access to the SQL db, without knowing the IP-adress ?

Comment: Is it a chance that you can provide static IPs to those laptops?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Managed Azure SQL Database, you might need to look into Azure ExpressRoute

[Managed Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/connect-application-instance#connect-from-on-premises)

You could also consider having a bastion server. The database can be locked down to only allow connections from the bastion server, and the bastion server is heavily protected using account information and Azure Active Directory.

[Azure Bastion Server](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/azure-bastion/)

```
User --> AD auth -->
User --> AD auth --> Bastion Server --> IP whitelist --> Database
User --> AD auth -->
```

Comment: Thanks. I will look into that!